# ActiveRecord Query Count Number of Relations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This is a Ruby 1.9.3/Rails 3.2 project.

Let's say I have a model called `Role`, and a model called `Employee`, linked through a `has_many`/`belongs_to` relationship. A role has many employees, and an employee belongs to a role. Both of these models belong to a `Store` object that has many employees and roles.

Each role has a `target_headcount` attribute, representing the ideal number of employees in that position. From there, I have methods like the following for `Role`:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  # Number of employees currently filling this role.
  def current_headcount
    employees.count
  end

  # Number of headcount above or below the target.
  def variance
    current_headcount - target_headcount
  end
end
```

Frequently, I need to get a collection of each role for which there is open headcount. I was doing this using the following class method for Role:

```
def self.open_headcount
  all.select { |r| r.variance < 0 }
end
```

However, I'm now using `meta_search`, a RubyGem which requires an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. I'd like to change `open_headcount` from a class method to a scope so that it returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, but I'm not sure if it is possible.

Comment: Would you be open to adding "open_headcount" as an integer to the roles table?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott I'd like to avoid it, but I guess if I had to I could use `after_create` and `after_update` hooks on `Employee` to set `Role#open_headcount`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is super old, but FTR I probably could have done it with by using a SQL query to count the number of employees for the role and subtracting from it the value of the target column.